# How to save timestamps with microseconds using dayjs?

Tags: javascript, time, dayjs

Problem flow:

- In frontend, I make a create request to persist an object
- In backend, the value of a date field is set and the object is persisted to the database.

  2022-01-01 12:00:00.123456
- In frontend, when I query for the object (using Dayjs for the date field) the precision is lost and I get

  2022-01-01T12:00:00.123Z
- Now if I save the object again the date value is also updated in the database with 3 digit precision.

This is very similar to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837018/how-do-i-save-timestamps-in-6-digit-numbers-using-daysjs), which is also answered, but there is no answer if I need to keep the microseconds. As it seems, this might not be possible with dayjs, but maybe someone has an idea how can I still keep the 6 digit precision.

Comment: you could save timestamps in milliseconds to db instead of dates

Comment: @GrafiCode I believe you misunderstood the problem. Database is fine, the problem is that the precision is lost when the data is queried and presented to the user. And if the user saves, the change reflects in the database,

Comment: I get it now. Maybe this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837018/how-do-i-save-timestamps-in-6-digit-numbers-using-daysjs

Comment: JavaScript dates are only precise down to milliseconds which is why you are losing the precision. The Temporal API proposal would allow precision down to nano-seconds but this is not implemented yet (other than using a polyfill)

Comment: You could manually add a microsecond property to each Date instance and read it back when serialising. You would need to wrap/replace the existing date parsing/serialisation but if DayJs creates a new date at any point then you would likely lose the extra info.

Comment: @GrafiCode You suggested a link that I already brought out in the question as not helpful to me.

Comment: @phuzi Thank you for the suggestion. I will consider it although it's not quite what I was hoping for.